# C言語の<stdio.h>のgets()が定義されません。

Tags: c

[編集済み]

Visual Studio Community 2022を使って、次のようなコードを作成しました。

```c
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int d;
    char A[10];
    scanf("%d",&d);
    gets(A);
    printf("d=%d, A[]=\"%s\"",d,A);
    return 0;
}
```

そして次のようなwarningが発生しました。
`warning C4013: 関数 'gets' は定義されていません。int 型の値を返す外部関数と見なします。`

コードを起動し、`3`(適当なint 1つ)を入力してEnterしたら
`gets(A);`が無視されてOutputは`d=3, A[]=""`になりました。

`gets()`関数を定義するために`<stdio.h>`を`include`していますが、warningのように`gets()`が定義されていなかったので使えなくなったと思われます。
C言語の初心者の私の間違ったところがありましたら教えて下さると助かります。

ただし、私の学校の授業から入力関数は`scanf()`、`gets()`、`getchar()`しかならってませんので、`scanf_s()`、`gets_s()`、`fgets()`などを使わない限りでお願いします。

Comment: 画面の一部だけ切り取って質問されても、`急にgets()が使えなくなりました。`という問題に対して正確な状況を表しているとは言えません。何をもって使えなくなったと判断したのか、タイトルの`急に定義されません`と表現が違うのは何故か等、情報は不足なく全てを提示してください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765) ちなみに`gets(A);`と`scanf("%d", &d);`の順番を逆にすると動作するようですね。そして`授業`というのなら疑問については先生/講師/助手?などの人に聞いた方が早くて正確だと思われます。

Comment: @kunif 順番入れ替えなくても動作はしますよ。しないと思ったのはプログラムが期待している文字列を入力しなかったからでしょう。

Comment: @alpha さん、質問記事のソースコードでビルドしてデバッグ実行すると`gets(A);`の入力待ちにならずに`printf("d=%d, A[]=\"%s\"",d,A);`の処理に行ってしまい、`A[]`の中身が空として表示されるので、`使えなくなった`と判断したのだと思われます。その状態を指して`動作しない`と考えました。順番を逆にすると入力待ちが2回行われて`gets(A);`の入力内容も`A[]`の中身として表示されるので`動作する`と表現しています。実際には質問者さんによる詳細な状況説明の追記待ちでしょうか。

Comment: @kunif 「しないと思った」は@kunifさんを指して書きました。`scanf("%d",&d)`は改行文字を消費しないので、改行文字を挿まずに"123abcdefg"等と入力すれば`gets(A)`は残りの"abcdefg"を読み取ります。

Comment: @alpha さん、どうもそのようですね。でもこうしたプログラムでは普通そんな入力は考えないですよね。こんな記事を見つけました。[C: scanf()関数の連続使用は注意](http://freeh.minim.ne.jp/minimini/develop/cscanf.html) `２つ目以降のscanf("%c")の代わりに、gets()やgetchar()を使ってもまずいでしょう。` 質問の問題そのものはこれが原因でしょうね。

Comment: @kunif 改行文字区切りで**も**読み取りたいなら、`scanf("%d\n", &d)`とすれば読み取れます。

Comment: 変な感じで私とalphaさんの会話みたいになっていますが、そういう内容に沿って質問者さんのためにalphaさんの回答を更新してみてください。

Comment: @kunif コメントありがとうございます！「scanf()関数の連続使用は注意」を読んで、次のようにコードを修正しました。
`scanf("%d",&d);
getchar();
gets(A);
printf("d=%d, A[]=\"%s\"",d,A);
`
Input: `104\nTenshi`
Output: `d=104, A[]="Tenshi"`
stack overflow不慣れで質問がよくありませんでしたら（スクショなど）すみません。

Comment: また質問する場合があることを考えて、質問記事を改善してみてください。そしてコメントを参考に解決されたなら、その内容を自己回答してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事も参考に。[自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @kunif ご丁寧にありがとうございます！、本当にたすかります。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gets()`はバッファーオーバーランが発生する危険な関数のため、Visual Studio 2015以降使用できなくなりました。
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/c-runtime-library/gets-getws?view=msvc-170

---

### 追記

プロトタイプ宣言されなくなっただけで、まだ定義はあるようなので、自分でプロトタイプ宣言すれば使えます。
ただし、正しいやり方ではないため、お薦めはしません。

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
char *gets(char *buffer);
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！gets()は危険性のある関数だったんですね。`char *gets(char *buffer);`でint型だったgets()がもうchar *型だと表示されます。`_MSC_VER`に関して検索してみたりして`_MSC_VER`も勉強になりました。